# fmt VS2019 warning, something I need to care about?

Tags: c++, fmt

using fmt 7.1.3 on windows with VS2019 (19.28.29914 for x86)

```
pTmp=fmt::format_to(dbuf, (fmtFlags & F_SHORT) ? "{:04d}{:02d}{:02d}" : "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}",
                    dt.year <10000 ? dt.year : dt.year %10000,
                    dt.month,
                    dt.day);
*pTmp='\0';
```

results in this famous message:

C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2630): warning C4582: 'fmt::v7::detail::arg_ref::value with [Char=char]::name': constructor is not implicitly called
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2630): note: while compiling class template member function 'fmt::v7::detail::arg_ref::value::value(int) with [Char=char]'
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2615): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'fmt::v7::detail::arg_ref::value::value(int) with [Char=char]' being compiled
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2635): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v7::detail::arg_ref::value with [Char=char]' being compiled
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2643): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v7::detail::arg_ref with [Char=char]' being compiled
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(3622): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v7::detail::dynamic_format_specs' being compiled
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(3161): note: while evaluating constexpr function 'fmt::v7::detail::parse_format_specs'
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2975): note: while evaluating constexpr function ::v7::detail::format_string_checkergiTimeStamp::getDateTime::<lambda_aeb89e23de062243f50ac9e48f895886::()::FMT_COMPILE_STRING::char_type,fmt::v7::detail::error_handler,unsigned int>::on_format_specs'
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(2997): note: while evaluating constexpr function 'fmt::v7::detail::parse_replacement_field'
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\format.h(3228): note: while evaluating constexpr function 'fmt::v7::detail::parse_format_string'
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1619): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void fmt::v7::detail::check_format_string<giULONG&,S,0>(S) with [S=giTimeStamp::getDateTime::<lambda_aeb89e23de062243f50ac9e48f895886>::()::FMT_COMPILE_STRING]' being compiled
C:\dev\gi2\strangers\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(2003): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'fmt::v7::format_arg_storefmt::v7::basic_format_context<fmt::v7::detail::buffer_appender<char,char>,unsigned int> fmt::v7::make_args_checked<giULONG&,S,char>(const S &,const unsigned int &) with [S=giTimeStamp::getDateTime::<lambda_aeb89e23de062243f50ac9e48f895886>::()::FMT_COMPILE_STRING]' being compiled
C:/dev/gi2/gi2cl/giOsal/src/giTimeStamp.cpp(1080): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'char *fmt::v7::format_to<char*,giTimeStamp::getDateTime::<lambda_aeb89e23de062243f50ac9e48f895886>::()::FMT_COMPILE_STRING,giULONG&,true>(OutputIt,const S &,giULONG &) with [OutputIt=char *, S=giTimeStamp::getDateTime::<lambda_aeb89e23de062243f50ac9e48f895886>::()::FMT_COMPILE_STRING]' being compiled

Is this something I can just ignore ?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue, can you please post the rest of your code so we can analyse it? 
A minimum compilable example would be perfect.